# При нажатии на кнопку “CLEAR LIST” должен очищаться фильтр поиска. Если в поиске ничего нет, то кнопка должна быть - disabled

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <input class="search-box" placeholder="Search products" type="search" id="find-product" />
         <button type="button" class="btn ml-auto" id="clear-list" disabled>Clear List</button>    
var $searchField = $("#find-product");
    // при вводе символов с клавиатуры в поле поиска, кнопка clear list, становиться активной
    $searchField.keyup(function(){
    //при нажатии на кнопку  сlear list поле очищается
        $("#clear-list").on("click", function(){
            $searchField.val('');
        });
         $("#clear-list").prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
```

Comment: А  в чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Проблемы было две, одну из них мне только что удалось решить, а вот со второй проблема, не могу понять, что нужно сделать, что бы когда поле пустое кнопка была disabled, а когда нет, то активной, как это правильно написать в скрипте?

Answer (score 1):

Не путайте PHP с JavaScript, в JavaScript нельзя передавать параметры переменные прямо в строку

Вариант либо

```
`${variable}`
```

либо

```
variable
```

```js
//clear list
var $searchField = $("#find-product");
$searchField.keyup(function() {
  $("#clear-list").prop("disabled", true); {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $("#clear-list").prop('disabled', false);
    };
  };
});
var $searchField = $("#find-product");
$("#clear-list").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").find($searchField).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <input class="search-box" placeholder="Search products" type="search" id="find-product" />
      <button type="button" class="btn ml-auto" id="clear-list">Clear List</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ)))